# How to proper dilute virgin Neem oil as pest control?

Tags: houseplants, pesticide

I had a recent infestation with *Fungus Gnats* on my houseplants, and one recommendation was to use Neem Oil as a natural pesticide for these pests.

I bought cold-pressed, unrefined/virgin Neem Oil, but failed terribly trying to dissolve in water to spray my plants. As it's a thick and semi-solid product, I tried using warm water ~40c, it worked for 1-2 minutes, but as soon that the water temperature dropped a bit, it formed solid again on the water surface, making it impossible to spray.

How to propper dilute/emulsify virgin Neem Oil into the water to spray it?